# Pivot_longer for multiple columns of repeated measurements data

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, tidyr

I am trying to use the `pivot_longer` function from the `dplyr` package to get my data into a long format. The current wide data involves 3 repeated measurements of the patients' age, their systolic blood pressure and if they used blood pressure lowering medication use (med_hypt), and the time invariant 'sex' variable.

The example data and what I've tried:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

wide_data <- structure(list(id = c(12002, 17001, 17002, 42001, 66001, 82002, 166002, 177001, 177002, 240001), 
                            sex = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), 
                                            .Label = c("men", "women"), class = "factor"), 
                            time1_age = c(71.2, 67.9, 66.5, 57.7, 57.1, 60.9, 80.9, 59.7, 58.2, 66.6), 
                            time1_systolicBP = c(102, 152, NA_real_, 170, 151, 135, 162, 133, 131, 117), 
                            time1_med_hypt = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                            time2_age = c(74.2, 69.2, 67.8, 58.9, 58.4, 62.5, 82.2, 61, 59.5, 67.8), 
                            time2_systolicBP = c(NA_real_, 146, NA_real_, 151, 129, 129, 137, 144, NA_real_, 132), 
                            time2_med_hypt = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                            time3_age = c(78, 74.2, 72.8, 64.1, 63.3, 67.7, 87.1, 66, 64.5, 72.9), 
                            time3_systolicBP = c(NA_real_, 160.5, NA_real_, 171, 135, 160, 151, 166, 129, 150.5), 
                            time3_med_hypt = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), 
                       row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

# Pivoting to a longer format
long_data <- wide_data %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols=!id,
    names_to=c(".value", "time"), 
    names_sep="_", 
    values_drop_na=FALSE
  )
```

This produces the following tibble:

```
# A tibble: 40 x 6
      id time       sex   time1 time2 time3
   <dbl> <chr>      <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 12002 NA         women  NA    NA    NA  
 2 12002 age        NA     71.2  74.2  78  
 3 12002 systolicBP NA    102    NA    NA  
 4 12002 med        NA      0     0     0  
 5 17001 NA         men    NA    NA    NA  
 6 17001 age        NA     67.9  69.2  74.2
 7 17001 systolicBP NA    152   146   160. 
 8 17001 med        NA      0     0     0  
 9 17002 NA         women  NA    NA    NA  
10 17002 age        NA     66.5  67.8  72.8
# ... with 30 more rows
```

What I want is for the column names to be id, time, age, sex, systolicBP, and med_hypt. With 3 rows per patient corresponding to the 3 repeated measurements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This probably adds nothing new to the already posted solutions, the only difference is the `regex` used for the `names_pattern` argument.

- If you notice some of your column names are separated by one `_` whereas others are separated by two `_`. `\\w+` captures any word character, now if I specify we have a number after this with `\\d+` as in `time3` in `time3_age`, we tell `pivot_longer` to store this part of the column names corresponding to `time3` in `time` column. Then the rest of the column names are used for the variable names we are trying to measure line `age`, `systolicBP` and `med_hypt`.
- It should be noted that if we use `\\w+\\d+` instead of `\\w+` only the rest will be captured as column names whether it is `med_hypt` with underscore or `systolicBP` without underscore. But if we use only `\\w+` it could also capture med and the resulting column will be `hypt` instead of `med_hypt`.
- In the end since I defined two capture groups, I have to define either `names_pattern` or `names_sep` in a way to specify how each of them are defined and separated.

```
library(dplyr)

wide_data %>%
  pivot_longer(!c(id, sex), names_to = c("time", ".value"), 
               names_pattern = "(\\w+\\d+)_(\\w+)")

# A tibble: 30 x 6
      id sex   time    age systolicBP med_hypt
   <dbl> <fct> <chr> <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 12002 women time1  71.2       102         0
 2 12002 women time2  74.2        NA         0
 3 12002 women time3  78          NA         0
 4 17001 men   time1  67.9       152         0
 5 17001 men   time2  69.2       146         0
 6 17001 men   time3  74.2       160.        0
 7 17002 women time1  66.5        NA         0
 8 17002 women time2  67.8        NA         0
 9 17002 women time3  72.8        NA         0
10 42001 men   time1  57.7       170         0
# ... with 20 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution.
Could you possible explain the names_pattern `regex` part of the dplyr code? I am not familiar with it's syntax. Would it be explained somewhere?

Comment: `regex` are introduced in `stringr` section of R for data science:
https://r4ds.had.co.nz/strings.html

Comment: Many thanks for the clarification. I will take a look at the corresponding R for Data Science chapters.

Do I understand correctly if, as I also have a variable with 3 underscores (e.g. med_hypt_calcant) that I change `"(\\w+\\d+)_(\\w+)"` to `"(\\w+\\d+)_(\\w+_\\w+)"`? So an extra `\\w+` at the end, seeing as I have an extra underscore?

Comment: In that case it won't capture `systolicBP`. Since some column names have 1 underscore and some have 2, and column names in our desired output may or may not have underscore, I chose to capture first part of the names which contains `time` in one column and the rest regardless of having 0 or 1 underscore as column names for the other columns.

Answer (score 4):

Since you have more than one underscore in certain column names it is better to use `names_pattern` instead of `names_sep`. `names_pattern` allows us to pass flexible regex patterns to capture from the column name.

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(wide_data, 
    cols=-c(id, sex),
    names_to=c("time", ".value"), 
    names_pattern = '(.*?)_(.*)$', 
  )

#      id sex   time    age systolicBP med_hypt
#   <dbl> <fct> <chr> <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 12002 women time1  71.2       102         0
# 2 12002 women time2  74.2        NA         0
# 3 12002 women time3  78          NA         0
# 4 17001 men   time1  67.9       152         0
# 5 17001 men   time2  69.2       146         0
# 6 17001 men   time3  74.2       160.        0
# 7 17002 women time1  66.5        NA         0
# 8 17002 women time2  67.8        NA         0
# 9 17002 women time3  72.8        NA         0
#10 42001 men   time1  57.7       170         0
# … with 20 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Ronak_Shah.
Could you possibly explain the `names_to` argument? How does this line of code capture what I want for column names exactly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly

```
   wide_data %>% 
      pivot_longer(
        cols=-c(id, sex),
        names_to=c(".value", "time"), 
        names_sep = "_", 
        values_drop_na=FALSE
      )

# A tibble: 30 x 6
      id sex   time       time1 time2 time3
   <dbl> <fct> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 12002 women age         71.2  74.2  78  
 2 12002 women systolicBP 102    NA    NA  
 3 12002 women med          0     0     0  
 4 17001 men   age         67.9  69.2  74.2
 5 17001 men   systolicBP 152   146   160. 
 6 17001 men   med          0     0     0  
 7 17002 women age         66.5  67.8  72.8
 8 17002 women systolicBP  NA    NA    NA  
 9 17002 women med          0     0     0  
10 42001 men   age         57.7  58.9  64.1
```